# Cancel payment in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, in-app-purchase, payment

Is it possible to cancel `SKPaymentTransaction` in `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing` from code?

I'd like to interrupt a purchase happening on iOS from an observer to try to sell another product instead.

Is there a way to remove the transaction from the queue to stop it from happening?  This throws an exception:

```
- (void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            ...
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: {
                // this throws
                [queue finishTransaction: transaction];
                break;
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which exception does it throw?

Comment: Cannot finish transaction in purchasing state

Comment: I don't know nearly enough to include this in an answer, but there may be a certain API diff in a certain beta that *may* (small chance) help you out.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is obviously going against [SKPaymentTransactionObserver protocol implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008262-CH1-SW3), and definitely something that Apple would not want.

You are finishing a transaction midway during status reporting. You seem to do it like aborting a file transfer when it is 51% done, but come on, there is real purchase going on, with user expecting some product (different than the one you are trying to sell him next)!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you cannot. If you want to do this, intercept the action before you submit the SKPayment request.

The `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing` status is purely informational.